# Using Django Views and Forms without a Models based Database

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am kind of new to Django (been writing Python for a while now) and I was wondering if it is at all possible to use the Views and Forms framework in Django without having the need for a database or the use of Models.

The content is dynamic, and gets populated into a dictionary each time the user launches the website. So I would like to leverage the Django Views and Forms but passing through the details from the dictionary and not from a Model Class (Database)

I hope I have explained myself correctly.

So to add onto this then.

If you had the following for a Models based class:

```
class TestClass(models.Models):  
    var1 = models.CharField(....)

class DetailView(generic.DetailedView):  
    model = TestClass
```

How could I use the DetailView class (Or any other django based View framework with a class based dictionary like this:

```
class TestObj(object):  
   def __init__(self):
       self.var1 = []

testdict = defaultdict(TestObj)
testdict['test'].var1 = ['blah']
```

Do I just use the dictionary in the model field under the DetailView class ?

please excuse me if I have anything typed incorrectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is totally possible.

However, if you decide not to have a database you will lose a chance to use many `contrib` features (like accounts, backend). From the "empty" project (made with `django-admin startproject`) you will need to remove most of `INSTALLED_APPS`, `MIDDLEWARE`, `context_processors` in `TEMPLATE`, set `DATABASES` to an empty `dict()` (see the comment from @spectras), maybe some other settings tinkering on top.

**Upd:** *(Since you modified your question significantly, here are more details)*

Using `django.db.models` doesn't make much sense without a database (pay attention on `db` in the path to `models` package). Some generic views (like `DetailView`) are made to spare your time when working with models, so using them will not make much sense neither.

If you don't need to save any of `TestClass` instances and their lifetime is limited to generating a response to a single user request, you should be fine without using django models at all. Using [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) will be sufficient.

```
    class TestClass(object):
        def __init__(foo, bar):
            self.foo, self.bar = foo, bar

    class MyView(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'my_template.html'

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['my_object'] = TestClass(foo="hello", bar="world")
            return context
```

In `my_template.html`:

```
    {{ my_object.foo }} {{ my_object.bar }}
```

Comment: I remember setting `DATABASES` to `{}` raised an error at some point. You had to provide a dummy `default` key, like this: `{'default': {}}`. Don't know if it still applies.